# OpenAM - Too many redirects issue

Tags: openam

Getting the following error when trying to access my protected application credentials are valid:

Has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a cookie related issue. Keep in mind that OpenAM's SSO tracking cookie is a domain cookie by default.

Some background and troubleshooting tips ...

http://blogs.forgerock.org/petermajor/tag/cookie/

Comment: Thanks, in the agent debug got the following error before my 403 Forbidden, can you offer any advice? WebtopNaming.getLBCookieValue(): server id is null, returning null

Comment: Turns out it was the way i had configured my active directory data store and authorisation settings